# How can I simplify the following DAX statement?

Tags: dax

I have a DAX statement that continues to grow in complexity, I feel as if I am writing it efficiently.  Can anyone help me understand how to simplify this statement?

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    ADDCOLUMNS (
                        ADDCOLUMNS (
                            Query_NewSales,
                            "isKit", NOT (
                                ISBLANK (
                                    LOOKUPVALUE ( Query_Kits[KitName], Query_Kits[KitName], Query_NewSales[Item] )
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        "AvgCPI", IF (
                            [isKit],
                            LOOKUPVALUE (
                                DAX_KitsPricedMissingRemoved[Total Price],
                                DAX_KitsPricedMissingRemoved[KitName], Query_NewSales[Item]
                            ),
                            LOOKUPVALUE (
                                DAXTable_NewPurchasesGroupedByItem[AvgCPI],
                                DAXTable_NewPurchasesGroupedByItem[Item], Query_NewSales[Item]
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    "isValid", NOT ( ISBLANK ( [AvgCPI] ) )
                ),
                "VenueFeeCalculated", IF ( [isValid], [Sold Price] * [Linked.VenueFee] ),
                "TransactionFeeCalculated", IF ( [isValid], [Sold Price] * [Linked.PaymentFee] )
            ),
            "Gross Profit", IF (
                [isValid],
                [Sold Price] - [VenueFeeCalculated]
                    - [TransactionFeeCalculated]
                    - [Shipping Cost]
            )
        ),
        "Total Fees", [TransactionFeeCalculated] + [VenueFeeCalculated],
        "Net Profit", IF ( [isValid], [Gross Profit] - [AvgCPI] )
    ),
    "Fees Percent", IF ( [isValid], [Linked.VenueFee] + [Linked.PaymentFee] ),
    "Shipping Percent", IF ( [isValid], [Shipping Cost] / [Sold Price] ),
    "Overhead Percent", IF ( [isValid], ( [Sold Price] - [Gross Profit] ) / [Sold Price] )
)
```

This code also seems inefficient because it creates a whole bunch of virtual tables, but without doing it this way I cannot reference the columns I am adding later in the query.  I do not want to have duplicates, triplicates, etc. as I continue the query.  It seems that there must be a way I can do this without all the nesting.

Comment: You could extract those ADDCOLUMNS statements into calculated columns or measures to break down the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the query to multiple measures instead:

```
define measure Query_NewSales[isKit] = SUMX(Query_NewSales, IF(NOT (
  ISBLANK (
    LOOKUPVALUE(Query_Kits[KitName],Query_Kits[KitName],Query_NewSales[Item])
  )), 1, 0))
measure Query_NewSales[AvgCPI] = SUMX(Query_NewSales, IF(Query_NewSales[isKit],
    -- lookup to DAX_KitsPricedMissingRemoved
   ,-- lookup to DAXTable_NewPurchasesGroupedByItem
))
EVALUATE ADDCOLUMNS(Query_NewSales, "IsKit", Query_NewSales["IsKit"], ...)
```